# SSIS - why my process tasks keep ending with result 1 (thus failing SSIS package)

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools, executeprocesstask

I am trying to move the contents of a folder to another folder.
Trying to keep this efficient, I decided to use a Process task:

[image]

While in SSDT, it works perfectly.

But when deployed to SQL Server SSIS on the same machine, it returns `PROCESS EXIT 1` and fails the package.

Is there anything here that stands out that could prevent this from working?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When SSIS packages are executed from SQL Server they access File System using the SQL Server Service Account `NT SERVICE\MSSQL$<Instance Name>` *(Where `<Instance Name>` should be replaced by the installed instance name)*. You have to Grant this account to access the selected directories or run the SQL job using a proxy account:

*SQL Server Serivce account Permissions:*

- [Configure File System Permissions for Database Engine Access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-file-system-permissions-for-database-engine-access?view=sql-server-2017)

*Setting proxy account:*

- [Running a SSIS Package from SQL Server Agent Using a Proxy Account](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2163/running-a-ssis-package-from-sql-server-agent-using-a-proxy-account/)
- [Create a SQL Server Agent Proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy)